# Screen privacy : Xposed module for keeping away prying eyes

Tags: security, screen, privacy, xposed-framework

I was traveling by crowded metro the other day and was engaged in a WhatsApp conversation tying up the exact location of our meeting.

I realised that my chat was pretty much visible to others close to me in that crowded metro. I don't blame them if they looked , I blame myself for not being more careful.

Anyway, searching for solutions lead me to [BlackBerry Privacy Shade](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blackberry.privacyfilter) (amongst others ), which does an admirable job of blanking out portions of screen ( reasonable permissions ) , as you can see from pictures from Play Store. Other apps weren't as good and some had questionable permissions

[image]

Only problem with this is that , I need to install BlackBerry Hub Services, which is a framework for Blackberry apps, to make it work ( trial app limitation can be overcome by downloading from [Izzy's F-Droid repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/)
)

**Is there any  Xposed module for achieving this ?**

(Not looking for apps , I am aware of couple of other apps on Play store but wasn't comfortable with them in terms of performance / permissions )

Needless to mention, Googling didn't help

**Device:** Moto X Play, Stock 6.0.1,  Rooted with Xposed framework installed